# Field Service Lightning Mobile Visualforce Login

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am trying to login into a salesforce community that is set up to use a VF page login page from the field service lightning mobile app. The view comes as a webpage instead of an FSL app view.

Also, when the login is set to standard community login, when I login into the FSL mobile app, I see the normal FSL app view.

Note: I am able to log in properly from the web.
The ask is to get the mobile view when logging in to the FSL app even when the default login is set as the Visual force page. Can someone help here if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a known limitation for Salesforce Field Service Lightning Mobile App.Visualforce pages aren’t supported in the app.
Please find link : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mfs_limits.htm&type=5

May be this can be an idea for future releases.